# Select Distinct Attribute and Print out Count of another even when the count is 0

Tags: sql, select

I don't quite know how I should describe the problem for title, but here's my question.
I have a table named `hello` with two columns named `time` and `state`.

```
Time | State
```

Here's an example of the data I have

```
1 DC
1 VA
1 VA
2 DC
2 MD
3 MD
3 MD
3 VA
3 DC
```

I would like to get all the possible time and the count of "VA" (0 if "VA" doesn't appear at the time)
The output would look like this

```
Time Number
1 2
2 0
3 1
```

I tried to do

```
SELECT DISTINCT time,
    COUNT(state) as Number
        FROM hello
        WHERE state = 'VA'
        GROUP BY time
```

but it doesn't seem to work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a conditional aggregation:

```
select time, sum(case when state = 'VA' then 1 else 0 end) as NumVA
from hello
group by time
```

I want to add that you should never use `distinct` when you have a `group by`.  The two are redundant.  `Distinct` as a keyword is not even needed in the SQL language; semantically, it is just shorthand for grouping by all the columns.

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT  TIME,
        SUM(CASE WHEN State = 'VA' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)
FROm    tableName
GROUP   BY Time
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/2b159/2)

Answer (score 0):

One rule of thumb is to get your counts first and put them into a temp for use later.
See below:

```
    Create table temp(Num int, [state] varchar(2))
    Insert into temp(Num,[state])
    Select 1,'DC'
        UNION ALL
    Select 1,'VA'
        UNION ALL
    Select 1,'VA'
        UNION ALL
    Select 2,'DC'
        UNION ALL
    Select 2,'MD'
        UNION ALL
    Select 3,'MD'
        UNION All
    Select 3,'MD'
        UNION ALL
    Select 3,'VA'
        UNION ALL
    Select 3,'DC'


     Select t.Num [Time],t.[State]
     , CASE WHEN t.[state] = 'VA' THEN Count(t.[State]) ELSE 0 END [Number]
     INTO #temp2
    From temp t
    Group by t.Num, t.[state]
    --drop table #temp2
    Select
    t2.[time]
    ,SUM(t2.[Number])
    From #temp2 t2
    group by t2.[time]
```